# Insert into Microsoft Access database in VB.Net

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridviewcolumn

I'm trying to develop a system which will be used by admin department to key in lecturer and student data.[image: example]

There will by many changes on the columns, the student might register other subjects such as Subject 10, Subject 11 and so on. And the lecturer could be Lecturer B, Lecturer C and so on.

Can you please suggest how should I create the database so that the user can change the columns' title and key in data according to their needs.

Comment: if the column values are dynamic, wouldnt it be better to have a table alone for the subjects and then map it to the students?

Comment: @c0dem0nkey What if the column could be anything? The user might add new subjects after years.

Comment: Construct a table for subjects alone and give them id's. The relationship between the student id and subject id will be one-to-many.

Comment: I'm thinking to add a hidden column with auto increment number for each record so that while calling data, I can select data by using the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/177388/Best-Practices-for-Database-Schema-Design 
You can download a sample here. Also , the thing about auto inrement id is mentioned here. take a look :)